# Delete the first column in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, formatting, notepad++

I have this file:

```
 206  06:06:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
 282  06:50:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
 353  07:27:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
 435  08:20:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
 482  08:39:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
 521  09:16:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
 667  10:42:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
 896  12:54:00.00   X               "Регион -1.30"                   00:01:30.00                    
1003  13:57:00.00   X               "Регион -1.30"                   00:01:30.00                    
1154  15:29:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
1272  16:23:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
1309  16:57:00.00   X               "Регион -1.30"                   00:01:30.00                    
1401  17:49:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
1434  18:07:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
1514  18:43:00.00   X               "Регион -2.00"                   00:02:00.00                    
1581  19:19:00.00   X               "Регион -1.30"                   00:01:30.00                    
1846  21:52:00.00   X               "Регион -1.30"                   00:01:30.00                    
1918  22:26:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00                    
1963  22:46:00.00   X               "Регион -1.00"                   00:01:00.00
```

There are spaces before non 4 digit numbers, e.g. first line `"206"` actually starts like `" 206"`

I need to get rid of the first column, so I need to only have

```
06:06:00.00 X "Регион -2.00" 00:02:00.00
```

for the first line, and so on.

I tried few thing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and regexp, but I always seem to just delete the whole line.

If you have other solutions rather than Notepad++ in mind, they would also do. The reason I chose Notepad++ was that this is not an original file, and its been through some formatting (Delete all lines not containing "Регион -"), so it it would be easier if all can be done in 1 place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+navigation keys, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click to do a block select of just that column. Then simply press <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: This can be interesting with a macro.

Answer (score 4):

try this regex replacement in notepad++:

```
search: ^\s*[0-9]+\s+
replace: nothing
```

If you want to delete all lines that doesn't contain 'Регион -' at the same time, you can change the pattern to:

```
search: ^(?!.*Регион -).*\r?\n?|^\s*[0-9]+\s+
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to go:

```
search what: ^.{5}
replace with: 'nothing'
```

Comment: this won't work on the first ones will it? They only have three digits in the initial number.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb This will _only_ work on the first one. `.{5}` matches 5 of any character (except newlines), but `^` only matches the very beginning of the input (unless multi-line mode is enabled).

Comment: Yes, but I thought the {5} meant it had to be five characters .... the first set of lines have only four characters to be replaced not 5.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb Spaces count as characters

Comment: Apologies ... I hadn't spotted the spaces before the first digits.

Answer (score 3):

This answer will both remove the first column, and remove lines that do not contain your search string.

Remove column number one first

Find what:      `^[ 0-9]+\s+(.*)`
   Replace with: `\1`

Remove lines not containing your desired string next.  That's a bit tough because the regex engine used by Notepad++ doesn't allow for the not operator so the (?!...) option doesn't work.  Instead you have to do it in multiple steps.

**Step 1** - Add a prefix to lines that contain what you want to keep

Find what:      `(.*KeepLinesWithThisString.*)`
   Replace with: `ZZZ\1`

**Step 2** - Remove lines that don't start with that prefix.

We know that the strings without the prefix will start with a number or a space, so this will blank those lines

Find what:      `^[ 0-9]+\s+(.*)`
   Replace with: `(nothing / leave blank)`

**Step 3** - Remove the prefix

Find what:      `^ZZZ(.*)`
   Replace with: `\1`

**Step 4** - Remove the blank lines

Highlight all the text of the document.  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or `Edit > Select All`
   `TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Blank Lines`
   `TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Surplus Blank Lines`

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for this:

```
"^[ 0-9]{6}"
```

(without the quotes)

and replace that with this:

```
""
```

(without the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first column in Notepad++:

1. For selcect the column that you want to remove : Alt+Drag
2. For cut : Alt+X

In this way, you can delete any column or multiple number of columns at a time.

Reference: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p7rMCGt_30&hd=1`

Answer (score 0):

Another way, trim the leading space first`Edit->Blank Operations->Trim Leading Space`.
Then search `^\d+`, replace with nothing. Then trim again. It could be a little more steps, but it is a way.